# Integration of $\xi$ function over rectangle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Hey simple question (I hope so),
I´m reading  *Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory*, and I don't get this step.

The author writes, this equation works by a "well known formula". But which is it, I don´t really get it?

$$
2N(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_R \frac{\xi^{\prime}(s)}{\xi(s)}\ ds
      = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Im\left(\int\limits_{R}\frac{\xi^{\prime}(s)}{\xi(s)}ds \right).
$$

$\xi$ is the Riemann $\xi$-function and R is a rectangle with vertices  $2+iT,~2-iT,~-1-iT,~-1+iT$ and N(T) is the number of zeros of $\xi$ till $\Im(s) \leq T$

Comment: read about the argument principle

Comment: yeah, I know that principle. But hwo is the relation to the imaginarty part of the Integral?

Comment: so you can say via this equation, it doesn´t change anything if u take the imaginary part of the integral?

Comment: Yes. That $\xi$ is analytic implies $\xi'/\xi$ is meromorphic with only simple poles with integer residues (telling the order $n _\rho$ of the zero of $\xi$ at $\rho$) so that $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_R \xi'/\xi(s)ds =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_R (\sum_\rho \frac{n_\rho}{s-\rho}+h(s))ds = \sum_{\rho \in R} n_\rho$ for some analytic function $h$. The next step is to use the functional equation to remove half of the contour. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_fonction_S(T)

Comment: Thank you for the nice link. I am always suprised what is in Wikipedia in other languages.